# Access EC2 port 9200 from external service

Tags: amazon-ec2, elasticsearch

I'm struggling to get EC2 and ElasticSearch up and running.  Specifically I'm trying to reach my node from outside Amazon's cloud for verification purposes.  I've set up the security group so that I have a "Custom TCP" rule on port 9200 and ElasticSearch is listening on that port, which I can see with `netstat -l`.  When I `curl -XGET https://localhost:9200` I get the response expected from ElasticSearch.  When I `curl -XGET https://publicIP:9200` from WITHIN Amazon (ie. another node that I have running) I get the response expected from ElasticSearch.  When I try to do the same request from my desktop I get "no response".  I can not, for the life of me, figure out why this is happening.

Comment: what error do you get from your laptop? Could you paste the command that you run and the output/error it gives?

Comment: I was using `curl -XGET http://ipaddress:9200` and was getting a 1 liner something along the lines of "no response."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things to check:

- Accessing the public URL of an instance from inside the amazon cloud will map to its private IP. In you test above, where you specify publicIP, did you use the public IP or public domain name? Make sure to test with the IP, not the domain name.
- If access to the public IP works from the same machine, try the same thing from another EC2 instance.
- Finally, you may have a firewall rule on your desktop, or your work network, preventing outgoing access on port 9200.

Comment: I had no idea it was possible or common to block 'outgoing' HTTP requests to certain ports.  Turns out this is what my work firewall was doing.  I changed the port that my service on EC2 was listening for HTTP on (from localhost:9200 to localhost:80) and am now able to get through.  Thanks!  I guess 80 is more typical to hit and so it doesn't raise flags like a request to ::9200 does.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Elasticsearch as a service, then go to /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml and make the

```
network.host: "0.0.0.0"
```

This solution worked for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me yet. With ES 7.0 when you aren't referencing LocalHost they add additional security requirements. E.g you could set discovery.seed.hosts.

Error Message: "at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured"

Comment: As an update, I had install the ec2 discover plug-in and then I updated my yml file to this:
discovery.seed_providers: ec2   
network.host: _ec2:privateIpv4_